# how to isolate data that are 2 and 3 sigma deviated from mean and then mark them in a plot in python?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, standard-deviation

I am reading from a dataset which looks like the following when plotted in matplotlib and then taken the best fit curve using linear regression.
The sample of data looks like following:

```
# ID X Y px py pz M R
1.04826492772e-05 1.04828050287e-05 1.048233088e-05 0.000107002791008 0.000106552433081 0.000108704469007 387.02 4.81947797625e+13
1.87380963036e-05 1.87370588085e-05 1.87372620448e-05 0.000121616280029 0.000151924707761 0.00012371156585 428.77 6.54636174067e+13
3.95579877816e-05 3.95603773653e-05 3.95610756809e-05 0.000163470663023 0.000265203868883 0.000228031803626 470.74 8.66961875758e+13
```

[image]

My code looks the following:

```
# Regression Function
def regress(x, y):
    #Return a tuple of predicted y values and parameters for linear regression.
    p = sp.stats.linregress(x, y)
    b1, b0, r, p_val, stderr = p
    y_pred = sp.polyval([b1, b0], x)
    return y_pred, p

# plotting z
xz, yz = M, Y_z                              # data, non-transformed
y_pred, _ = regress(xz, np.log(yz))      # change here           # transformed input             

plt.semilogy(xz, yz, marker='o',color ='b', markersize=4,linestyle='None', label="l.o.s within R500")
plt.semilogy(xz, np.exp(y_pred), "b", label = 'best fit')  # transformed output
```

However I can see a lot upward scatter in the data and the best fit curve is affected by those. So first I want to isolate the data points which are 2 and 3 sigma away from my mean data, and mark them with circle around them. 
Then take the best fit curve considering only the points which fall within 1 sigma of my mean data

Is there a good function in python which can do that for me?

Also in addition to that may I also isolate the data from my actual dataset, like if the third row in the sample input represents 2 sigma deviation may I have that row as an output too to save later and investigate more?

Your help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code that goes through the data in a given number of windows, calculates statistics in said windows, and separates data in well- and misbehaved lists.
Hope this helps.

```
from scipy import stats
from scipy import polyval
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_data = 10000
fake_data_x = np.sort(12.8+np.random.random(num_data))
fake_data_y = np.exp(fake_data_x) + np.random.normal(0,scale=50000,size=num_data)

# Regression Function
def regress(x, y):
    #Return a tuple of predicted y values and parameters for linear regression.
    p = stats.linregress(x, y)
    b1, b0, r, p_val, stderr = p
    y_pred = polyval([b1, b0], x)
    return y_pred, p

# plotting z
xz, yz = fake_data_x, fake_data_y                            # data, non-transformed
y_pred, _ = regress(xz, np.log(yz))      # change here           # transformed input             

plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(xz, yz, marker='o',color ='b', markersize=4,linestyle='None', label="l.o.s within R500")
plt.semilogy(xz, np.exp(y_pred), "b", label = 'best fit')  # transformed output
plt.show()

num_bin_intervals = 10 # approx number of averaging windows
window_boundaries = np.linspace(min(fake_data_x),max(fake_data_x),int(len(fake_data_x)/num_bin_intervals)) # window boundaries
y_good = [] # list to collect the "well-behaved" y-axis data
x_good = [] # list to collect the "well-behaved" x-axis data
y_outlier = []
x_outlier = []

for i in range(len(window_boundaries)-1):

    # create a boolean mask to select the data within the averaging window
    window_indices = (fake_data_x<=window_boundaries[i+1]) & (fake_data_x>window_boundaries[i])
    # separate the pieces of data in the window
    fake_data_x_slice = fake_data_x[window_indices]
    fake_data_y_slice = fake_data_y[window_indices]

    # calculate the mean y_value in the window
    y_mean = np.mean(fake_data_y_slice)
    y_std = np.std(fake_data_y_slice)

    # choose and select the outliers
    y_outliers = fake_data_y_slice[np.abs(fake_data_y_slice-y_mean)>=2*y_std]
    x_outliers = fake_data_x_slice[np.abs(fake_data_y_slice-y_mean)>=2*y_std]

    # choose and select the good ones
    y_goodies = fake_data_y_slice[np.abs(fake_data_y_slice-y_mean)<2*y_std]
    x_goodies = fake_data_x_slice[np.abs(fake_data_y_slice-y_mean)<2*y_std]

    # extend the lists with all the good and the bad
    y_good.extend(list(y_goodies))
    y_outlier.extend(list(y_outliers))
    x_good.extend(list(x_goodies))
    x_outlier.extend(list(x_outliers))

plt.figure()
plt.semilogy(x_good,y_good,'o')
plt.semilogy(x_outlier,y_outlier,'r*')
plt.show()
```

[image: outliers and friends]